# Creating a gzip stream using zlib

Tags: gzip

How to create a gzip stream using zlib? any code available?

Answer (score 0):

Here is gzip [file format](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html). What you need is to output the member header followed by zlib-compressed bytes.

I hope that's enough...